# Python CSV - Error with line that cointains NULL Byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

In Python 3, is this the best way to workaround NULL Bytes found in rows on CSV?

```
file = open("file.csv", "rb")
data = csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in file), delimiter=",")
```

Comment: if it works, well your filter looks okay. I'd drop the "b" of "rb", making your code compatible with python 3.

Comment: Define 'best'. It depends on what you would like to happen to the null bytes.

Comment: Are you reading a Unicode UTF16 file? Try reading the file with utf-16 encoding (or something like utf-16_le / be, I'm not sure about the exact terms).

Comment: Best way to workaround = best way to bypass this situation. No, I'm not working with utf-16 files. Yesterday, I saw others answers on Stackoverflow that suggested to use conversions to deal with utf-16 files, but isn't my case. In fact, this is a csv generated by InstaPy project. Removing the b from rb mode working as I planned. Thanks guys! ✌️

Comment: Suggest you add `newline=''` to the `open()` though which is recommended in the CSV docs.

Comment: After regarding all those replies, my final version of this problem is:
`file = open('file.csv', 'r', newline='')
data = csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in file), delimiter=',')`